# Dupplicating data to to match up with a drop down list depending on what has been selected

Tags: excel, vba

Right I've spend all day looking / trying to find something that could do this, could someone please point me in the right directions please.

*please note im using office 2013*

I have a Drop down list on Sheet 2 which pulls data from sheet 1 and then changes the values on sheet 2 by using Vlookup, depending on what has been selected from the drop down list.
However there is a variably column on sheet 2 that needs to be changeable which effects one of the Vlookup points of from sheet 1.

so i was thinking for example
`IF sheet1A2 = sheet2A2 Then sheet2b2 = sheet1b2` 
therefore saying if the two drop down values on both sheets match then output the same value in the same row on sheet 1, therefore allowing the data to move up and down the column on sheet 1 depending on what has been selected on sheet 2.

I've not done VBA and excel in ages so very rusty btw 
Thank you for the Help.

Comment: Can you explain your predicament a bit more... It truly seems like a vlookup should do what you're looking to accomplish, but I'm sure I'm just not understanding your question....

Comment: Sheet 1 has a table set with part data which is set by the user and part calculations which come from the data entered on sheet 1. Sheet 2 has the drop down list which pulls the calculations from sheet 1 (depending on that is selected (using Vlookup) ) however this is the tricky part, Sheet 2 has one column worth of data that needs to be changed depending on the selection of the drop down list. but this columns data also effects the calculations on sheet 1 therefore what every is selected on sheet 2 drop down needs to match up with the column of the calculation.

Comment: Still confused... The way you're describing it, it sounds like a circular reference.... How does the data in sheet2 affect sheet1?? How would choosing a value in the drop-down affect the data in sheet2 and, hence, how would that affect sheet1 which, in turn, affects sheet2??

Comment: This code is in 'sheet1 - '=('sheet2'!B2/1000)*(C2)' which goes down the Column, the B2's column data in sheet 2 changes depending on the drop down selected. But the dropdown selected also determines the data that vlookup bring back. So for example I select "test 1" from the dropdown list and enter the value of 10 for B2 in sheet 2 the Role that i have the data will show that test 1 has this data which then fills across in sheet 2 however the calculation above on Sheet 1 could change depending on the data in b2 and the item selected from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it thanks anyways.`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A12,'Proposed Rations'!$A$2:$J$15,MATCH($P$1,'Proposed Rations'!$A$1:$J$1,0),0),"")"` was the item that i needed.